# Data Tables bsavestate issue

Tags: datatables

By keeping **bstate=true**
it would save the sorted state of data and column filtering.
now by keeping this bstate=true.
i want to *clear the column  filtering field* and *keep the sorted data as it was in asc or desc order* as it was before.

what shall i do?

```
bstate=true;
```

the column filtering is in `<tfoot>`

http://birdchan.com/home/2012/11/26/datatable-clear-filtering/comment-page-1/

Comment: To clarify: you want to clear a filter field, and not reload the data?

Comment: yes i want to clear filter field and not reload data

Comment: `oTable.fnDraw();` is causing the data to reload. Remove that and it will work as expected